# jQuery get li from variable containing ul

Tags: jquery

I need get `li` from a variable that contains `ul` which was previously received :

```
var previousPage= $( "ul" );
$(previousPage 'li') //Doesn't work
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Do it with the second parameter of $-method like this

```
var previousPage=$( "ul" );
$('li', previousPage);
```

This parameter specifies the context to search for the 'li'-tag...

And if you want the first `li` do this:

```
$('li', previousPage).first();
```

You can also combine the selectors like this:

```
$(previousPage.selector +' li');
```

Comment: Might as well fix the `var=previousPage=$( "ul" );` syntax bug as well :)